# AngularJS directive to pass click action or do ui-router state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a button (an `a` tag) that appears many places on my site.  It's called "View Demo", and in some cases it simply calls an `ui-sref` to navigate to a demo page:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="hamburger-push" target="_blank">
   View Demo
</a>
```

which would be simple to make a directive out of, except in *some* cases it has an ng-click tied to the controller of the hosting page:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="mod.modals.basicMessage()">
  View Demo
</a>
```

So I am trying to make a directive which would have an atribute for each kind of link, and make those attributes optional.  This way, when using the directive I can include the relevant one:

```
<view-demo-button clickaction="mod.modals.basicMessage()"></view-demo-button>
```

or

```
<view-demo-button linkaction="stateNameToGoTo"></view-demo-button>
```

To clarify, the button must be able to *either*

1. Call a function on the host controller , or
2. Call $state.go in the host controller.

However, I can't get this right.  My template is:

```
<div class="view-demo" >
  <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="ctrl.hasLink" ui-sref="{{ctrl.linkaction}}" target="_blank">
    View Demo
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="ctrl.hasClick" ng-click="{{ctrl.clickaction}}" target="_blank">
    View Demo
  </a>
</div>
```

The directive is:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').directive('viewDemoButton', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        'linkaction': '@?',
        'clickaction': '@?'
      },
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'core/directives/pb-view-demo-button.template.html',
      controller: function ($state) {
        var _this = this;

        _this.hasLink = _this.linkaction || false;
        _this.hasClick = _this.clickaction || false;


      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
  });
})();
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach or if this sort of thing even works.

I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozHkrDA5jAVvRiVFxnBh?p=preview) of where it's at now, which is non-functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view-demo-button` directive can be simplified to a component:

```
  app.component('viewDemoButton',{
      bindings: {
        'linkaction': '@?',
        'clickaction': '&?'
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: `
         <div class="view-demo" >
           <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.viewDemoClick()">
              View Demo
           </a>
         </div>`,
      controller: function ($state) {
        var _this = this;

        _this.viewDemoClick = function () {
          console.log("viewDemoClick invoked");
          if (_this.clickaction) {
            _this.clickaction();
          }
          if (_this.linkaction) {
            $state.go(_this.linkaction);
          }
        };
      }
  });
```

Have the component template invoke a function in the component controller. Take actions based on the attributes of the component element.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/GGAkGmONPyJMvFNIt2px?p=preview)

Comment: That's great.  We've only recently moved to Angular 1.5 so I haven't had much experience with components yet.

Answer (score 1):

use `&` binding in your scope. that way it will be treated as a callback. That is how `ng-click` works.

```
  bindToController: {
    'linkaction': '&?',
    'clickaction': '&?'
  },
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I pass it along to the template? Assigning `ctrl.clickaction` to the ng-click in the template does nothing and `{{ctrl.clickaction}}` throws an error.

Comment: Works for the `ng-click`.  For the `linkaction` param, I had to go back to `@?` and then bind to it in the template: `ui-sref="{{ctrl.linkaction}}"`